# Anti-virus warning - 1 attachment contains a virus or blocked file.Downloading this attachment is disables

Tags: java

"Anti-virus warning - 1 attachment contains a virus or blocked file.Downloading this attachment is disables". I have this problem when i download the file.I am in new in java. Anyone please help me to resolve this problem using Java.

Comment: If the virus checker is implemented correctly, you won't be able to "resolve this problem using Java".  The whole point of a virus checker is to stop people from doing dangerous things .... like downloading dangerous content.  If you really need to download dangerous (or potentially dangerous) content, it should be the user or system administrator's decision, and a Java app should not be able to subvert this.

Comment: The correct way to solve this is for the user to temporarily turn off the virus checker, download the file to a quarantined area, check it thoroughly, and if it is safe then move it out of the quarantine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the Android Gmail app. Put it in drive if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Well,

it could either be a false alert, or the file does indeed contain a Virus. 
You should provide more information - like what kind of file? Where does it come from? Did you make it? etc.

The way it is, this question is not really useful.

Sorry for the reply. I wanted to comment, but my reputation did not let me do so.

Cheers,

Ben